# Bootable usb - mac still useable

Tags: boot, mac, macosx

There is this tutorial on how to create a bootable usb stick [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)
Will it still start with osx if the usb stick is not plugged in? Because I don't want to destroy osx, and I want to choose. Or I have heard, that a software called bootcamp would let you choose, but I can't find an explanation what it actually does.

Would be nice, if,somebody could help me

Kamik423

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a bootable USB stick in that guide does not change your install of OS X or your ability to boot OS X. Bootcamp is Apple software that allows you to install Windows as a dual-boot option; there is no support for running Ubuntu under Bootcamp.